# .Each() with input array

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble getting `.each()` function to work with an array of textboxes.  I can't seem to figure out what I'm missing.

If I used `$("input[type=text]").each()` it works fine.

If I used `$("[name=age[]]").each()` it doesn't work.

```
<?php 
  //this code is abbreviated
  foreach ($dbresult as $obj) {$output = "<input type='text' name='age[]' value='" . $obj['age'] . "'";}
?>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#form").submit(function () {
        $("[name=age[]]").each(function () {
            if (!$.isNumeric($(this).val())){return false;}
        return true;});
});
```

Comment: Post your rendered HTML, not the PHP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to esacpe `[]`, thus change  your selctors as

```
 $("[name=age\\[\\]]")
```

[DOCS](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \.

Or you can use [Attribute Starts With Selector [name^="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/), like

```
$("[name^=age]")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
$("input[name='age[]']").each()
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("[name=age[]]")` doesn't seem to be a valid selector.  Try `$("[name^=age]")` instead.

Comment: This doesn't work if you have also other fields with names starting with the letters "age", for example "agelimit"

Answer (score 0):

if you are using array  you have to try following code

```
$.each( yourarrayname, function( key, value ) {
  alert( key + ": " + value );
});
```